# How to generate PDFs with Unicode Bangla characters?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am facing a problem with generating reports in PDF format with PHP. I have tried the FPDF, TCPDF, and HTML2PDF libraries but they do not support all Unicode Character sets.

TCPDF supports Czech (cz), Danish (da), German (de), Spanish (es) etc. But I need to output both English and Bangla text. But the Bangla characters are being replacing with `?`s.

Is there a PHP library which supports all Unicode Character sets? How I can output Bangla charater sets with FPDF, TCPDF, or HTML2PDF?

Comment: TCPDF supports unicode, utf-8, what's the problem are you getting with using it, did you follow their instructions?

Comment: Your problem most likely has to do with font and not character set. You are missing a font which is why it cannot be rendered. Find your preferred font, add it somewhere the library can find it, and try again.

Comment: thanks @ Preveen Kumar & Burhan Khalid. Acconding to fpdf instruction when i generating corresponding font .php and .z file through  [link](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/) ..then getting error "Error: Font license does not allow embedding".

Comment: @arif04cuet - sounds like the license for your font does not permit embedding, which is necessary for non-standard fonts that readers may not have on their machine. Buy the same font with an embedding license, or use a different font that you know will permit this (when buying a font, always check with the seller). There may even be a free TTF font available for the language you need.

Comment: i have finally found a free TTF and generated corresponding .php and .z file and stored them on font directory.i have impletemented font as like as below

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Nikosh', '', 'Nikosh.php');
$pdf->SetFont('Nikosh', '', 35);

but output is not desired
"à¦†à¦°à¦¿à¦« of the East 2011"

Comment: @PraveenKumar,@halfer..can you please tell me what encoding i need to set for Asian Character?Default Encoding in FPDF is "cp1252".

Answer (score 0):

FPDF has support. Please check out this: http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=5142&t=5142

Comment: i have finally found a free TTF and generated corresponding .php and .z file and stored them on font directory.i have impletemented font as like as below

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddFont('Nikosh', '', 'Nikosh.php');
$pdf->SetFont('Nikosh', '', 35);

but output is not desired
"à¦†à¦°à¦¿à¦« of the East 2011"

Comment: In Adobe Reader, make sure you uncheck **Use Local Fonts only**

Comment: can you please tell me what encoding i need to set for Asian Character?Default Encoding in FPDF is "cp1252".

Comment: Finally i am able to render My Bengali font in PDF but font rendering is not perfect.according to [Adding new fonts and encoding support](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm) tutorial what will be the encoding type for Asian Character set?